# Hide Image with Razor MVC

Tags: html, jquery, css, c, .net

How do I hide an svg image if it’s globally in the footer. Can I use CSS and get page id and hide it on a certain page?

```
#page1 svg{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41223975

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Render page in some views Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692301/hide-render-page-in-some-views-razor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use javascript for this

```
jQuery(function($) {
        var path = window.location.href; 
        // because the 'href' property of the DOM element is the absolute path
        $('svg').each(function() {
            if (this.href === path) {
            $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```